# Postgres COPY FROM data formatting before insertion

Tags: c++, sql-server, postgresql, libpq

I'm creating PostgreSQL database client that ought to work as substitute for SQL Server client. Both clients are written in C++. One of the supported operation is bulk copy from given instance of class containing `std::string ReadChunk()` method.

For now I use libpq functions:

```
PQexec(connection, "COPY tablename FROM STDIN");
while(reader.HasNext()) {
     PQputCopyData(connection, reader.ReadChunk().c_str());
}
PQputCopyEnd(connection);
```

But turns out that I should also be able to truncate too long varchars and insert `NULL` between two consecutive `\t` if they are representing nullable column. Is there any way to perform this conversion on the database side, writing C triggers or something similar? Or should I implement argument parsing on the client side, something like SQL Server `bcp_bind`?

Answer (score 0):

My implementation pushed basic data processing on database client. It seemed to be a good solution, since data source was database independent and it traversed read data only once - I needed only truncation and `NULL` insertion.

So final solution consisted of class `RowReader` with methods `bool HasNext()` and `NextRow(CRow&)` reading next row to the table representation and abstract `RowSender` with implementations for every database.